# Direct access to auto-synthesized instance variables in subclasses?

Tags: objective-c, properties, accessor, member-variables, synthesize

For efficiency I want to access the member variable associated with a property in a subclass. If I have a property declared like:

```
@interface Mumbo : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic) GLKVector3 position;
@end
```

In the implementation of Mumbo I can refer to position either as self.position or directly as _position (the default synthesized member variable - I am not using @synthesize).  I use the latter for efficiency in some cases to avoid copying structures.

However, in subclasses I cannot refer to _position unless I change the interface to

```
@interface Mumbo : NSObject {
    GLKVector3 _position;
}
    @property (nonatomic) GLKVector3 position;
@end
```

This seems to work.  However, am I guaranteed that the automatically synthesized member variable will coincide with the one that I've explicitly declared in the braces?  I can't find any definitive documentation on the subject.

Comment: Are you sure you save some processing time by doing this? I'm pretty sure you won't notice a difference unless you're using the position heavily in loops.

Comment: Yes, Fabian, this is inner loop stuff.  The sample uses something familiar like GLKVector3, which is small.  But my real code uses a struct that is much more involved.  Returning a struct by value through a chain a methods potentially involves multiple copies and I have verified that the time involved is significant.  It also varies enough that I think I'm taking L1 cache hits, at least.

Comment: Okay, it's all good then. ;) In the WWDC sessions they said that if in doubt, you should declare the @synthesize and iVar if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-synthesized variables use a leading underscore be default, so you are right there.

But the way you declare your iVar - makes it public, but auto-synthesized variables are private. Which is why you can access it from outside the class.

Comment: Is there a documentation about the naming of auto-synthesized backing variables? I didn't know about the underscore convention.

Comment: @zoul Maybe in the Clang docs - but I got this from WWDC 2012 vid 405 (Modern Objective-C)

Comment: Thanks. Do they encourage using the auto-synthesized instance variables? It sounds to me like they’re supposed to be “private” even to the class they belong to, being used only through the accessors. The association between the property and the underscored instance variable looks like too much magic to me.

Comment: They do - in that same vid IIRC they actually say to use the property version every but in set up and tear down. I don't think it's magic though. It's equivalent to declaring a private backing store with a leading underscore.

Comment: +1: use the accessor all the time. you'll never notice the performance hit, except in cases of a loop running tens of thousands of times or more.

Comment: Although: If I am reusing the result of an accessor many times, i.e. self.window, I'll do this: `NSWindow * window = self.window` before accessing `window.frame`, `window.backgroundColor`, etc., you know?

Comment: Yes, leaving out @synthesize is now recommended as of Xcode 4.4(?) as I learned at the last WWDC.  I've removed it from all of my code since I was using the underscore convention already (as recommended in the iTunes U Stanford course).

Comment: Nielsbot, in your example the property is an object so self.window is returning a reference and is not copying a struct by value as in my case.  I also need to modify my struct's contents so returning it by value wouldn't allow me to do that.

Comment: Thanks, Abizem.  I hand't noticed the private scope used by default.  In my real code, I have \@protected, which seems to give me what I'm looking for.